# How to do .slice to show top 3 result on filter function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter, slice

I want to show the top 3 result via .slice function.

How to do that after filter function

I have tried to add .slice after the match in filter function, but it's didn't work properly

Below is the code

```
filteredEntitySearch () {
      let entity = this.options
      return entity.filter((entity) => {
        return entity.name.match(this.searchQuery).slice(0, 4)
      })
    },
```

**For some context** the main function (filteredEntitySearch) is designed for

- get all the match entity with the search query (searchQuery)
- show the 3 top result

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have made several mistakes.

1. filter function parameter name should not be same with array name for better understanding
2. slice function used in wrong place
3. slice parameter should be slice(0, 3) if you want 3 result

Your code should be like this:

```
filteredEntitySearch () {
      let entities = this.options
      return entities.filter((entity) => {
        return entity.name.match(this.searchQuery)
      }).slice(0, 3)
    },
```

Comment: How if i want to add timeout to it?

Answer (score 1):

Move it outside of your filter:

```
filteredEntitySearch () {
      let entity = this.options
      return entity.filter((entity) => {
        return entity.name.match(this.searchQuery);
      }).slice(0, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you get results after filter(17 elements) but only the top 3 are shown

```js
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,6,5,5,5,4,4,3,3,22,2,2,1,1,4,5,6,77]
console.log(arr.filter(e=>e>3).slice(0,3))
```